# how to show image in swift

Tags: html, ios, swift4

Imagine I have this json:
[image]

I could convert Json to string and show it by below code:

```
extension String {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }
    var htmlToString: String {
        return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

but I can’t display the image in json. How can I do that?

Comment: Image src has url with schema which uses "http:" iOS 10 onwards if your app needs to access anything on internet should use "https", if you desperately want to access some content over http then you will have to add `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` and set value to yes. Have you done that?

Comment: Uhm...you have a JSON that has HTML in it so you'll have to extract that URL by parsing the HTML or load all the HTML into a webview.